# How to use if to answer based on what is found

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have excel like this.

[image]

I want end result like this

[image]

Means

I want to Put formula in column c to get grade based on what is in column B.

If in B is Check mark, C should show "A"

If in B is Cross mark, C should show "B"

If in B is Question mark, C should show "C"

Comment: Where to ask this type of questions? Why I am getting negative ratings?

Comment: This type of question is on-topic here. The possible reason why you've received the down-vote is the lack of effort demonstrated to solve your problem on your own (voting is anonymous, so nobody knows who had voted). Have a look on our help center to learn more about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on Máté Juhász's answer, which will put "C" in column C if any character other than a check mark or cross mark is in B, this will specifically check for a question mark and leave column C blank if column B isn't any of the 3 characters that you want:

```
=IF(B2="<check mark>","A",IF(B2="<cross mark>","B",IF(B2="?","C","")))
```

(You would, of course, want to fill that formula down into the other cells in column C.)

Comment: Work Just Fine. Thank you very much. Where to ask this type of basic questions?

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(B2="<check mark>","A",IF(B2="<cross mark>","B","C"))`

Just replace mark descriptions with the exact character you have in your sheet.

Comment: Work Just Fine. Thank you very much. Where to ask this type of basic questions?